# How can I know that I have reached end of the file(EOF) using batch scripting

Tags: batch-file

I am working on batch scripting. I am struck at the of point of comparing my variable with EOF (end of the file).

```
set "file=abc.csv"
 for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%file%") do (
     if <what should I use here to know I have reached EOF?>
           echo %%a%.
     else
           echo %%a%,)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] and add your complete batch file, together with an explanation of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Are all the files you run this on going to be different?

Comment: No!! I have to read only a single file.

Comment: i don't understand. when the file reaches EOF, the for loop breaks. did you mean the `last line`??